# Куда закидывать изображения в проекте cocos2d-x?

Tags: c++, cocos2d

Я создала проект в visual studio. Далее написала код. Теперь меня интересует в какую папку проекта нужно закинуть изображения со спрайтами.

Comment: В папку Resources (вы же создавали болванку проекта через cocos.py надеюсь?)

Comment: Нет, болванку не создавала. Подскажите, как это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здравствуйте.

Порядок действий:

1. В папку "Recources" кидаете свои рисунки;
2. Затем в проекте `Add->Existing Item`;
3. Заходите в папку "Recources" выбираете нужные рисунки.

Answer (score 1):

создаем фрейм через консоль:
cocos new NAMEyourGAME -p com.YOURWEBSITE.NAMEyourGAME -l cpp -d ./FOLDERFORYOURPROJECTS/
далее переходим в папку с фреймом, команда cmake и увидите варианты компиляции.

Изображения по умолчанию в папку Resources, но лучше сразу позаботиться о мультискрине и создать папки для разных разрешений, привязки к этим папкам прописать в AppDelegate.cpp

```
   
  auto fileUtils=FileUtils::getInstance();
  auto screenSize=glview->getFrameSize();
  std::vector resDirOrders;
  if (screenSize.width == 2048 || screenSize.height == 2048)
    {
      glview -> setDesignResolutionSize(1536, 2048, ResolutionPolicy::NO_BORDER);
      resDirOrders.push_back("ipadhd");
      resDirOrders.push_back("ipad");
      resDirOrders.push_back("iphonehd5");
      resDirOrders.push_back("iphonehd");
      resDirOrders.push_back("iphone");
    }
  else if (screenSize.width == 1024 || screenSize.height == 1024)
    {
      glview -> setDesignResolutionSize(768, 1024, ResolutionPolicy::NO_BORDER);
      resDirOrders.push_back("ipad");
      resDirOrders.push_back("iphonehd5");
      resDirOrders.push_back("iphonehd");
      resDirOrders.push_back("iphone");     
    }
  else if (screenSize.width == 1136 || screenSize.height == 1136)
    {
      glview -> setDesignResolutionSize(640, 1136, ResolutionPolicy::NO_BORDER);
      resDirOrders.push_back("iphonehd5");
      resDirOrders.push_back("iphonehd");
      resDirOrders.push_back("iphone");

    }
else if (screenSize.width == 960 || screenSize.height == 960)
    {
      glview -> setDesignResolutionSize(640, 960, ResolutionPolicy::NO_BORDER);
      resDirOrders.push_back("iphonehd");
      resDirOrders.push_back("iphone");
    }
  else
    {
      resDirOrders.push_back("iphone");
      glview -> setDesignResolutionSize(320, 480, ResolutionPolicy::NO_BORDER);
    }

  fileUtils->setSearchPaths(resDirOrders); 
  //Load your first scene
  auto scene = MainMenu::createScene();
```